# YouTube private videos via Google OAuth2?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, youtube, youtube-api

I am building a closed system for training. It is a login with Google OAuth 2.0 as in the admin panel I have a white list emails that can use the system (log in).

I am trying to use YouTube private videos (using YouTube Data API v3), by embedding with YouTube player and access token/refresh token.
Generally, I have everything set up and working, but in order for users to watch the video I have to have explicitly given them access to the video (in YouTube studio - manually).

Also to note that the project is in a test process (I mean not published to the domain - in Google Console).

Is there any way in my project that users can watch the YouTube private videos without setting additional access in YouTube Studio - in the video itself the user's email?

What I tried and works for YouTube private videos (not unlisted) is manually assigning an email to the video itself, but it doesn't work for me since I'm supposed to have a lot of users and videos.